# Print html form without onClick event handler

Tags: html

I am compiling an html form from text, data and img files and at present it is printed by onClick window.print(). I wish to print the form unconditionally once it has been loaded onto the screen but I can't see the way forward.

Comment: Could you explain (clarify) your goal? Why do you want to print that form automatically (and thus not filled by user's data)? It does not make sense.

Comment: All of the client data has been put into the form from stored data triggered by a client ident system. The form is compiled "on the hoof" and I just want to print it as soon as it is complete - the client wants a printed form, not a displayed form. I have tried using window.load and onload window.print but it didnt work. Maybe there is a simpler way - i am just trying to modify an old site which was written by someone else.

Comment: What about jQuery and `document.load`?